# Asp Core 3 Preview 4 - JSON camelcase

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

Having migrated my ASP.Core API from 2.2 to 3.0, I'm finding some oddities with the way that DTO's are being returned when serialised using JSON.

Originally, all my responses would come back as camelcase. Yet, everything now is set as PascalCase.

I've tried settings the following and also DefaultPropertyNamesContractResolver.:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
             // Return JSON responses in LowerCase?
             options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

             // Resolve Looping navigation properties
             options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

This is how the controller returns the object.

```
// GET: api/Projects
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> GetProjects()
{
    return await _context.GetAll();
}
```

It's odd, even Swagger reports the result should return in camelcase, but the JSON object is always capitalised in Pascal.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It seems a bug in `ASP.NET Core preview 4`. You can submit issue in here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore

Comment: Thank you, @TanvirArjel. Are you confident I'm not just missing something out before I raise a bug report?

Comment: As per as I am concerned ASP.NET Core by default serilazition format is CamelCase.  Then even you are trying with `options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();` buty still its PasCal case. Its weird.

Comment: Yea, I'm not really sure what else to try at this stage. Thanks, I'll raise it on the GitHub page.

Comment: have you tried:
`(options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver as DefaultContractResolver).NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(true, false);`

Comment: Thanks Siggi, I was referencing Newtonsofts library from a Swashbuckle Nuget package, rather than Microsofts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using Swashbuckle with the project and it was referencing the NewtonJson dependency from that package, rather than referencing the Microsoft Newton Package.